# Raspberry Pi 2 model B green led is blinking 8 times

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-wheezy, raspbian-jessie, noobs

When I am booting up my Raspberry Pi 2 model b, green led is blinking for 8 times.

I read all the post related to it and done necessary things without success.

I changed SD card, tried Noobs, Wheezy, Jessie images, changed power supply but I'm not able to make it work.

Comment: +1 for giving us relative information and doing your own research so this wasn'the a "My Pi doesn't work please help" kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this list](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern) eight flashes of the green LED mean:

> SDRAM not recognised. You need newer bootcode.bin/start.elf firmware.

To me that includes the case of a real hardware defect. So if you tried to use current OS images (thus including current firmware) and the error prevails it might just be a damaged Pi.